# Div error. Just floating where it shouldn't

Tags: css, html

Okay so yesterday I posted about a grid error I was getting, but now when I try to put a div after the grid squares. Their css is:

But see all the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/W2tBa/1/

I want the footer be extended as the header is but aslo have the cushion of 3px on the top. Also jsfiddle is displaying it correct so im not sure whats going on.

For some reason the jsfiddle is working but on my computer it isn't. I am running XAMPP on my MacBook. Ill try real quick and see what happens on my website. See it is the same on my website here: http://harrisonbh.com/new/ it still doesn't work.

```
//Ignore this StackOverflow is making me put this here
```

Comment: Why would some one down vote this?

Comment: Hey! Know how to solve? haha

Comment: I'll downvote it as well if you don't make it clearer... You briefly describe the problem, give us the jsfiddle that *works* and you expect an answer... how?

Comment: Yeah, what exactly is wrong? the footer looks the same as the header

Comment: I updated the above. See here: harrisobh.com/new

Comment: website doesnt exist.......

Comment: harrisonbh.com i mean. Sorry

Comment: Yea ill upload the new stylesheet using @shomz answer.

Comment: Check it out now i updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `clear: both` on the `footer` div fixes it.

Comment: Thank you, unlike the others *huh hem* you answered it without threatening. Haha, jk everyone on stack overflow rocks!

Comment: Haha, I did say I'll downvote your question unless you explain the problem better though! ;)

Comment: Im kidding, geez why the downvote. I explained further. Sorry I sometimes have troubles putting questions into words, sounds weird but eh, it is what it is.

Comment: It wasn't from me since you corrected it... And I know you're kidding. Here, I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: Thank. Haha :) probably from yentup. Hehe. But I got my problem fixed, thanks to you, and I guess I don't have much to complain about.

Comment: No problem... Perhaps you could remove the huge CSS chunk (downvoters probably hated it) since we have everything on jsfiddle and your site now.

Comment: I wouldn't have added it but the question submit form made me.

Comment: Hey dude, this isn't spam at all but if your interested in maybe helping me make a submission system for a project im working on(saveapaste4.me) go ahead and shoot me an email at harrison(at)harrisonbh.com